# namespaces of extended external classes

Tags: php, namespaces

this question is addressed to all php naespace gurus.
the scenario is as follows.

./namespace.inc.php - class creating instance of b using namespace

```
<?php
  require_once("a-wons.class.php");
  require_once("b-wns.class.php");
  // create an instance of class B with own namespace defined
  $b = new foo\B();
?>
```

./a-wons.class.php - class which class b inherits from without namespace

```
<?php
  // has no namespace definition and is an external class
  class A {}
?>
```

./b-wns.class.php - class with namespace that extends a

```
<?php
  namespace foo;
  class B extends A {}
?>
```

on invoking 'namespace.inc.php' one runs into a namespace error resulting from external class a has no namespace definition set providing the childs
namespace as default

```
$ php namespace.inc.php
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'foo\A' not found in b-wns.class.php on line 5
```

i know i could set class' a namespace to e.g. `namespace bar;` and use an alias definition like `use bar\A as A;` in namespace.inc.php but as **I DO NOT WANT TO MODIFY CLASS A** as it is probably an external class and **I WANT TO KEEP MY OWN NAMESPACES** i just asked myself if

**it is possible to masquerade class' a namespace keeping my own namespaces in class b and upon invocation in in namespace.inc.php?**

Comment: `class B extends \A {}`?

Comment: thanks for your comment, i already tried that. it did not work :/

Comment: @u_mulder thanks for the hint :) i just tried to used this in conjunction with alias definition. that seem to work currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply using `class B extends \A {}` as @u_mulder suggested does not work but in conjunction with alias definition for namespaces it seem to work.

./b-wns.class.php

```
<?php
  namespace foo;
  use \A as A; // needs to be added otherwise 
               // extending external class A will not work
  class B extends A {}
?>
```

i don't know yet if that probably leads to other errors so feel free to add any comment. thank you.